# caught segfault in [R] function

Tags: c, r

I am very new to C but know my way around [R].  This error could be a very stupid mistake in C.

My C code does kernel smoothing.

**When I comment out the last line of code my function works:  results[i] = v; **

This call kills R:

> new.y<-zsmooth2( x=c(0:80000), xpts=dat$V2, ypts=dat$V4, h=10000)

*** caught segfault ***
address 0x1184f8000, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .C("kernel_smooth", as.double(x), as.double(ypts), as.double(xpts),     as.integer(n), as.integer(nxpts), as.double(h), result = double(length(xpts)))
 2: zsmooth2(x = c(0:80000), xpts = dat$V2, ypts = dat$V4, h = 10000)

**C-code:**

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void kernel_smooth(double *x, double *ypts,  double *xpts, int *n, int *nxpts, double *h, double *results){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < *n; i++){

        double nsum = 0;
        double dsum = 0;

        double z = x[i] + *h;
        double y = x[i] - *h;

        for(j = 0; j < *nxpts; j++){

            if(xpts[j] < y){
                continue;
            }   
            if(xpts[j] > z){
                break;
            }   
            double d = (xpts[j] - i) / *h;
            double r = dnorm(d, 0, 1, 0);
            nsum += r * ypts[j];
            dsum += r;  
        }   
            Rprintf("test:i %d\n", i);  
            double v = nsum / dsum;
            Rprintf("test:v %f\n", v);  

         results[i] = v;  
    }

}
```

**R-code:**

```
 dyn.load("~/github/ZevRTricks/smoother1.so")
 zsmooth2<-function(x, ypts, xpts, h){
    n <- length(x)
    nxpts <- length(xpts)
    dens  <- .C("kernel_smooth", as.double(x), as.double(ypts), 
                as.double(xpts), as.integer(n), as.integer(nxpts), 
                as.double(h), result = double(length(xpts)))
dens[["result"]]
}
```

Comment: you have C code posted in the C# forum..

Comment: C and C# are two totally different languages. You don't just use their names interchangeably.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't easily use C# with R. So is the code really C?

Comment: Changed tag, this is definitely C

Comment: Your example is not reproducible without dat$V2 and dat$V4.

Answer (score 2):

`xpts` and `ypts` are vectors, and in your C code you are trying to access elements 1 to `n` in each of them. `n` is the length of `x`, which is 100 times longer in your second example than in your first example. Compare `seq(from = 0, to = 80000 by = 100)` to `0:80000`, (and while you're at it you can drop the `c()` from around the `0:80000`).

So I guess that `xpts` and `ypts` are at least 801 elements long, but less than 80001 elements. You've messed up your indexing somewhere.

Note also that you pass `x` to your C code, but don't actually use it for anything.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but I am pretty sure you're correct.  Could I ask how I can a return an index (for an array) for values greater than x and less then y?

Comment: If you're talking about a for loop in C, something like `for (i = x; i < y; i++){ array[i] = something}`. Depending on the details, you might need to switch that to `i = x + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however still catching the error after fixing up my code.  I updated it above.

Comment: You are still accessing `n` elements of `results`, but `results` is only as long as `xpts` while `n` is the length of `x`. Your code will fail whenever `x` is longer than `xpts`. I don't know what you're doing, but I think your algorithm is wrong.